# Why is my email form field too tall, and the text is centered?

Tags: css, forms, email, field

From what I can tell, my form field is completely standard. The page is at http://worldcastmovie.com/login.php

The email field on the right is two lines tall, and input is centered. My code doesn't seem to reflect this, so is there another place within my site I should be looking?

Thanks in advance!
Ryan

Here's the code in question:

```
                                            <div>
                                                    <label>Name:</label>
                                                    <input type='text' name='name'/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                    <label>Email:</label>
                                                    <input type='text' name='email' id = 'email'/>
                                                    <div class='error'>
                                                            Please enter your email.
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                    <label>City:</label>
                                                    <input type='text' name='city'/>
                                            </div>


                                            <div style='position:relative'>
                                                    <label>Desired Username:</label>
                                                    <input type='text' name='username' id='username'/>
                                                    <div class='error'>
                                                            Please choose different username.
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                    <label>Desired Password:</label>
                                                    <input class='input' type='password' name='password' id='password'/>
                                                    <div class='error'>
                                                            Please specify different password.
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                    <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                                                    <input class='input' type='password' name='cpassword' id='cpassword'/>
                                                    <div class='error'>
                                                            Please confirm your password.
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--<div>
                                                    <label>Video:</label>
                                                    <input type='file' name='video' />
                                            </div>
                                            <div>

                                                    <input type='checkbox' name='terms' style='margin-left:12px;margin-top:20px;' id='terms' /><span style='margin-left:10px;'>I have read and agree to the <a href='terms.php'>terms and conditions</a></span>
                                                    <div class='error'>
                                                            You have to read and agree to the terms and conditions.
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>-->

                                            <input type='image' src='/images/register.png' id='submit'/>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: instead of using `padding-top: 10px;` try `padding: 5px 0;` or remove it completely, `padding: 0`. Its up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's matching the rule on `#email` on line 62 of `style.css`:

```
#email {
text-align: center;
color: black;
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

In other words: the element ID `email` is not used uniquely as it should, this rule is probably meant for some other element requiring the `padding-top` and the horizontal centering.

A simple right click and 'inspect element' would've shown you this as well.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad! Sorry, I didn't build the site myself and wasn't thinking style sheet. New to this, thanks so much for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer to compensate for whoever didn't understand this was the correct answer and downvoted it  :D

Answer (score 0):

you should make the email field left aligned currently it is centered and make the padding top to 0

```
 #email {
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: @RyanJames you welcome,you may mark it as right ans :) if it works for you

Comment: Sorry man, Niels also answered it AND got downvoted, so I chose him. Wish I could choose two, because you were right!

Answer (score 0):

You are using padding-top to make the email field look larger, I would play around with height not padding if you want it to the text to be vertical aligned to the middle and not padding-top..

```
#email {
text-align: left;
color: black;
height: 100px;
}
```